# how to implement this sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table structure like this:

```
id, country, state, num1, num2
1 CANADA GH 45 34
2 CANADA HY 43 32    
3 USA XY 20 30
4 USA AB 30 40
5 USA CD 20 55
6 USA DE 43 54
```

and I would like to first sort this by first column (Country) such that the entries belonging to most frequently appearing countries comes first. Since USA has 4 entries and CANADA has 2, this should first appear like:

```
    id, country, state, num1, num2
    1 USA XY 20 30
    2 USA AB 30 40
    3 USA CD 20 55
    4 USA DE 43 54
    5 CANADA GH 45 34
    6 CANADA HY 43 32
```

and if the count of the two countries would be the same then the first one to be displayed would be the one which has highest aggregate of the third column: in this case USA has 20+30+20+43 as aggregate and CANADA has 45+43, so even if USA and CANADA tied in counts, USA would still appear higher because it has the higher aggregate. And lastly, I would like the ordering within the countries to be such that the third column of integers are in ascending order, and if there is a tie, then the second column should be arranged alphabetically. For USA, since the ordering 20, 30, 20, 43 would need to be in ascending order, there is a tie between first and third entry, which is broken by considering that XY has lower priority than CD. So the final output would be:

```
        id, country, state, num1, num2
        1 USA CD 20 55 
        2 USA XY 20 30
        3 USA AB 30 40
        4 USA DE 43 54
        5 CANADA HY 43 32 
        6 CANADA GH 45 34
```

any idea on how I would achieve this?

EDIT: this is what I tried:

```
SELECT country, state, num1, num2
FROM 
    country_table
ORDER BY 
    COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY country) DESC,
    SUM(num1) OVER(PARTITION BY country) DESC,
    num1 ASC,
    state;
```

But this doesn't seem to work. It gets confused when there are two countries with same number of entries.

Comment: Do you have window functions available? If not, join with a subquery that returns the count of entries and sum of the third column for each country, and sort by those.

Comment: Your code works fine: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=18ed0a63bf18a0aaeca6a9933c23d5f1

Comment: First create a table that computes the ordering info:  `SELECT country, COUNT(*), SUM(...) FROM tbl`  Then JOIN that to the original table ON country, and use these two columns for ordering.  (No need for "Windowing functions".)